# delete single data without deleting the entire row in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to delete a single data from my table but I don't want to delete the whole row.

My fields are:
`Bboard_id(INT,PK), postedby(VARCHAR), image(VARCHAR('image path only'))
Bboard_id = 1, postedby = admin, image = 'uploads/gallery/1.jpg'`

I use this code in deleting `delete FROM tblbboard where Bboard_id=1`

I just want to delete the image data from Bboard_id=1 but the whole will be deleted, is there any possibility wherein only the image data will be deleted?

Answer (score 4):

`update tblbboard set image = NULL where bboard_id = 1` should do as you ask